# convert a string to a nested tcl list

Tags: string, list, tcl

See the code below:

```
> foreach a {k l { jo k } {jo i } k } { puts $a}
k
l
jo k
jo i
k
```

The question is, what happens if I get a string which has a string representation of the list:

```
> foreach a "{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }" { puts $a}
k l { jo k } {jo i } k
```

How can I convert the string `"{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }"` to a list which is identical to: `{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }`
Using subst and eval, but that did not work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string looks like it is holding a list, so let's try `lindex`…

```
% foreach a [lindex "{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }" 0] { puts $a}
k
l
 jo k 
jo i 
k
```

Answer (score 3):

The ["splat" operator](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) works too:

```
% foreach a "{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }" { puts $a}
k l { jo k } {jo i } k 
% foreach a {*}"{k l { jo k } {jo i } k }" { puts $a}
k
l
 jo k 
jo i 
k
```